# Save arraylist of objects so they are restored when app restarts.

Tags: java, android, android-activity, arraylist, bundle

How can I save my arraylist of objects so they are restored when app restarts. I have tried to store it in bundle and restore it using savedinstancestate but everytime I restart the app, all data is gone and it starts from beginning(with empty list).

my code for Area class is

```
 public class Area implements Parcelable {

// region Properties

public String id;
public String name;
public double latitude;
public double longitude;
public float radius;

// end region

// region Public
//creates a named area
public Area(String name, double latitude, double longitude, float radius){

    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    this.name = name;
    this.longitude= longitude;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.radius = radius;

}
// endregion
public Area(Parcel in){
    id = in.readString();
    latitude = in.readDouble();
    longitude = in.readDouble();
    name = in.readString();
    radius = in.readFloat();

}

   //getters

public String getId(){return id;}
public double getLatitude(){return latitude;}
public double getLongitude(){return longitude;}
public float getRadius(){return radius;}
public String getName(){return name;}

    //setters

public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
public void setLatitude(double latitude){this.latitude=latitude;}
public void setLongitude(double longitude){this.longitude=longitude;}

public void setRadius(float radius) {
    this.radius = radius;

}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(id);
    dest.writeDouble(latitude);
    dest.writeDouble(longitude);
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeFloat(radius);


}
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Area> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Area>()
{
    public Area createFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        return new Area(in);
    }
    public Area[] newArray(int size)
    {
        return new Area[size];
    }
};

@Override
public String toString(){return this.name + "       " + this.radius;}
// endregion
}
```

Used this method for saving and restoring in bundle

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Here you can save your data
    // If you want to store your ArrayList, it should implement Parselable
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("STORE_KEY", areas);
}

/**
 * Restoring data
 */
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    areas = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("STORE_KEY");
}
}
```

Oncreate method is

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    areas = new ArrayList<Area>();
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
       areas = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("STORE_KEY");
    }
    if (areas.isEmpty()) {
        Log.d("area list lala", "is empty");


    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < areas.size(); i++) {

            Log.d("area list lala", areas.get(i).getName());
            Log.d("area list lala", String.valueOf(areas.get(i).getRadius()));
        }

    }
```

There is also overrided onresume function

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}
```

Comment: write data to file and then read data from the file when app is started?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to permanently store parcelable custom object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839400/how-to-permanently-store-parcelable-custom-object)

Answer (score 1):

How about storing your objects in SQLite database or db4o ([more about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Db4o)), that is specifically designed for storing objects.

[This is](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076120/java-se/flatten-your-objects.html) the article about serialization of your objects into the byte stream.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
I don't know if this is possible in Java but in c# I would use XML Serialization...

Comment: We are talking about java not C#

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your objects ... Throw the following into a utility class

```
public static void writeObject(String fileName, Object object) throws Throwable
       {
           FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
           write(file, object);
           file.close();
       }


       public static Object readObject(String fileName) throws Throwable
       {
           if (!(new File(fileName)).exists()) return null;
           else
           {
               FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(fileName);
               Object object = read(file);
               file.close();
               return object;
           }
       }

       private static void write(OutputStream os, Object object) throws IOException
       {
           GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(os);
           ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(gos);
           oos.writeObject(object);
           oos.close();
           gos.close();
       }

       private static Object read(InputStream is) throws Throwable
       {
           GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is);
           ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(gis);
           Object object = ois.readObject();
           ois.close();
           gis.close();
           return object;
       }
```

Then serialize your object like:

```
Util.writeObject("C:\\myList.obj", myListArrayObject);
```

Then on startup de-serialize back into your object like:

```
myListArrayObject= (ArrayList<String>)Util.readObject("C:\\myList.obj");
```